# Bulk insert using FORALL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, oracle11g, forall

I am currently using the following code to do a bulk insert of 50 million rows:

```
declare cnt number;
BEGIN 
    select max(run_ver_issue_id) into cnt from "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE";
    FOR x IN 1 .. 50000000 LOOP
         INSERT INTO "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE" NOLOGGING ("RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID","CUST_ISSUE_ID","TITLE","ORIGINAL_ISSUE_ID","SOURCE_FILE_LINE","DISPLAY_TEXT","RUN_VER_ID","SANDBOX_SRC_FILE_ID","ACCOUNT_ID","ISSUE_STATE","CURRENT_SEVERITY","INSERT_TS","MODIFIED_TS","CWE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_LINE","CURRENT_EXPLOIT_LEVEL","CNT","SOURCE_FUNCTION_PROTOTYPE","SOURCE_RELATIVE_LOCATION","SOURCE_SCOPE","PROCEDURE_NAME","PROCEDURE_HASH","PROTOTYPE_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH_COUNT","STATEMENT_HASH_ORDINAL","SUBMODULE_PATH") VALUES (x+cnt,2,..);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

It takes almost 6 hours it to finish. The table does have an index on **RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID**, but still doesn't help. I tried using **FORALL**, getting an error **PLS-00430: FORALL iteration variable X is not allowed in this context** for the below code:

```
declare cnt number;
BEGIN 
    select max(run_ver_issue_id) into cnt from "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE";
    FORALL x IN 1 .. 5
    INSERT INTO "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE" NOLOGGING ("RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID","CUST_ISSUE_ID","TITLE","ORIGINAL_ISSUE_ID","SOURCE_FILE_LINE","DISPLAY_TEXT","RUN_VER_ID","SANDBOX_SRC_FILE_ID","ACCOUNT_ID","ISSUE_STATE","CURRENT_SEVERITY","INSERT_TS","MODIFIED_TS","CWE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_LINE","CURRENT_EXPLOIT_LEVEL","CNT","SOURCE_FUNCTION_PROTOTYPE","SOURCE_RELATIVE_LOCATION","SOURCE_SCOPE","PROCEDURE_NAME","PROCEDURE_HASH","PROTOTYPE_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH_COUNT","STATEMENT_HASH_ORDINAL","SUBMODULE_PATH") VALUES (x+cnt,2,.....);
END;
```

I would request you to please provide your suggestions and comments as to how I can speed this up.

Comment: You are not using `FORALL` correctly. Refer the link: http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_rittman_bulk%20binds_FORALL.htm  for a better understanding and usage.

Comment: You can try this `insert into "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE" NOLOGGING ("RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID","CUST_ISSUE_ID",..."/The Rest Of the Columns") select rownum+cnt,2,..... from dual connect by rownum<=50000000;`. However this risks overflowing the rollback segment, so you better use small batches of say 1000, much like the example below, BUT using a  commit statement efter each loop iteration.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do this as a single insert-select statement?

Comment: That `NOLOGGING` is just a table alias, by the way. Did you mean to `alter table mv_run_ver_issue nologging` and then `insert /*+ append */ into mv_run_ver_issue` perhaps? (I hope the `MV` prefix doesn't indicate that it's a materialised view.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use this:

```
declare 
    p_array_size number := 100000; 
    type array is table of number;
    l_data ARRAY;
    cursor c is select rownum seq_no from dual connect by rownum <= p_array_size; 
    cnt number;
begin 
    open c;
    loop
        select max(RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID) into cnt from "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE"; 
        fetch c bulk collect into l_data limit p_array_size;
        forall x IN 1 .. l_data.count
        insert into "ABHINAV"."MV_RUN_VER_ISSUE"("RUN_VER_ISSUE_ID","CUST_ISSUE_ID","TITLE","ORIGINAL_ISSUE_ID","SOURCE_FILE_LINE","DISPLAY_TEXT","RUN_VER_ID","SANDBOX_SRC_FILE_ID","ACCOUNT_ID","ISSUE_STATE","CURRENT_SEVERITY","INSERT_TS","MODIFIED_TS","CWE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_ID","TEMPLATE_FILE_LINE","CURRENT_EXPLOIT_LEVEL","CNT","SOURCE_FUNCTION_PROTOTYPE","SOURCE_RELATIVE_LOCATION","SOURCE_SCOPE","PROCEDURE_NAME","PROCEDURE_HASH","PROTOTYPE_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH","STATEMENT_HASH_COUNT","STATEMENT_HASH_ORDINAL","SUBMODULE_PATH") 
        values(l_data(x)+cnt,2,'0pJDFy1viDnN2Ku66XPl458gKakF4xz4pTawwoOZYCt0yR2YOw7tH1Mk3oKQ7ynuyasbBjBXr1teBbBdmIsJReIM3kbzWY7H4c6CVgVaw',NULL,230969,'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',74228,2,6120,8096,581270,'26-Sep-12 01:30:00','21-Feb-00 03:52:00',7531,1,NULL,5203,12726,'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',48913,'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','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','VZ7DnA7vcofPtMwPPulenNpC7ErJPaLsWy2XipWF02D1ZwzXCwC8hJ6MrII3PKYGLklG0SzrMqU0','BfjqAIQ6gwX3Xhjl338BqTJaMZUKxzMcdTovIPF6iD3lXeW4szUglzWNmFKXlYQ71cRQM1v0BAZwUqf1lRZfCsKnPlJIDdgy0JmHrfVHGGy84c3NMf7TRuNOeqj7xUYCV','Aox4fssjHKLaZwTS0Bq',57753,NULL,'C:\DOCS\TEMP75');
      exit when c%notfound;
    end loop;
    close c;   
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you artificially limit the result set with `rownum`? There's no need for that here. Also, a batch size of `500000000` is most probably overkill here - I would start with 100 or 1000.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp ok, it works with 5000000(5million), but for 50million gives memory error

Comment: @To be able to use *cursor* i've limited the result set with rownum, and the question gives the value of 50000000

Comment: No, that's not a reason to limit the number of rows returned from the cursor. Plus, it just doesn't make sense to have the same limit in the cursor *and* as a batch size - if the result is 50M (by the way 50,000,000 is 50 million, not 5 million), setting the batch size to 50M means that it will only ever have 1 batch and 1 batch exactly - so there's no need for the loop!

Comment: @JeffreyKemp :) i'm aware that  50,000,000 is 50 million, but said 5m didn't give error, whereas 50m gave.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the limit clause is used to limit the number of rows fetched in each iteration of the loop. Typically it's 100, but that may or may not be the best value for each system. See [Connor's answer](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9534257800346922469) for more info on why a smaller limit may better than larger ones. Also, your memory error - when you do a bulk collect of 50 million rows, you'd better make sure you have sized the PGA adequately! Part of why a (small-ish) limit clause is used - to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Be careful, change your EXIT WHEN to l_data.count = 0, else you will end up not processing all of the rows your retrieve when there are not an even number of rows. See the "kicking the %NOTFOUND Habit" section here:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks for your response. This is my whole insert script : github.com/fdrgiit/Get-Direction/blob/master/insert.txt Can you please guide me as to how can I modify your above code that you provided for bulk insert. Also the reason I have select before I start inserting records, is because run_ver_issue_id column is primary key and I am trying to maintain that integrity as well as follow a sequence.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan So isn't it possible to edit your query to a insert of 50 million rows at once?

Comment: @arsm4 it's possible of course, provided that the PGA sized adequately, as "Boneist" told.

Comment: @Gary_W ok, thank you very much read mentioned part of article. I treasure Steven Feuerstein by the way.

Comment: @arsm4 if you want to insert all your rows in one go, write a select statement that generates the results that you want, and then put that in an `insert into ... select ...` statement. There would be no need for looping, that way.